# How do I print a plot with only keep the plot panel content in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to save a picture from a plot which only retains the plot panel contents.

But when I used the below code, there's a white margin at the left and bottom of the plot.

How do I get rid of it?

Thanks.

```
ggplot()+
  stat_function(fun = ~ -(.x-2) ^ 2 + 3, size = .5, linetype = 'dashed', color='white') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 4)) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "pt"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black", colour = "black"),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: You can use `theme_void()` to have an empty theme. Not 100% sure this only preserves the panel though.

Comment: ... `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt")` would be another option.